# Garbage value for arabic content in Outlook 2007

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I am writing a newsletter application, and the **newsletters are in Arabic**. The newsletters **load up correctly in browser** but when opened in **Outlook 2007,** strange text comes up. If the email is marked as spam and then viewed, the page looses its style but the content in Arabic loads up correctly.

So my question is: What meta tags in the html, or settings in outlook has to be done to fix this issue.
Since the Arabic content gets displayed correctly in a spam email, I think all the language dependencies are correctly installed.

ScreenShots

1. Screenshot of mail in inbox:

   [image: Image with style but random text for arabic]
2. Screenshot of mail in Spam Folder:

   [image: Image with correctly displayed content but no style]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution to this problem. Convert each arabic character to its unicode value and then send the news letters.

For eg.

> حاولت يوما مقاومة دموعك المتساقطة لا إراديا عند تقطيعك بصلة؟! حسنا,
>   يمكنك ذلك مع Onion Goggles والمصممة بطريقة فريدة

becomes

```
&#1581;&#1575;&#1608;&#1604;&#1578; &#1610;&#1608;&#1605;&#1575;
&#1605;&#1602;&#1575;&#1608;&#1605;&#1577;
&#1583;&#1605;&#1608;&#1593;&#1603;
&#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1578;&#1587;&#1575;&#1602;&#1591;&#1577;
&#1604;&#1575; &#1573;&#1585;&#1575;&#1583;&#1610;&#1575;
&#1593;&#1606;&#1583; &#1578;&#1602;&#1591;&#1610;&#1593;&#1603;
&#1576;&#1589;&#1604;&#1577;&#1567;! &#1581;&#1587;&#1606;&#1575;,
&#1610;&#1605;&#1603;&#1606;&#1603; &#1584;&#1604;&#1603;
&#1605;&#1593; Onion Goggles &#1608;&#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1589;&#1605;&#1605;&#1577;
&#1576;&#1591;&#1585;&#1610;&#1602;&#1577;
&#1601;&#1585;&#1610;&#1583;&#1577;
```